# I want (1) import data from web to be instances to owl ontology, (2) users can retrieve results over web application

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

I created OWL ontology with classes and properties.

I want to

(1) import continuously data from web to be instances to this ontology so it becomes dynamic ontology

(2) The users can retrieve results over web application linked to OWL ontology.

The interface of the users allows to select some keywords from drop-list and also ask users to insert keywords for some questions. Then SPARQl should retrieve the results from the dynamic OWL ontology.
Please advice how to do that?

Comment: Triple stores, RDF Stremas, ETL, Kafka, Git, etc. - not sure what exactly you expect as an answer here, nobody will design a framework on Stackoverflow. Can you make your question more specific please?

Comment: How can I import instances from the web to my owl ontology? Also, how can I allow the user to get answers to his queries? Users will not deal directly with the owl ontology. He should have user friendly web site then he can make queries and results retrieved from ontology.. Virtuoso is used to integrate the owl ontology. But I want to fed the ontology from Web and I want to allow users to get answers from ontology through web. What tools snd techniques I should have?